# How can I remove those html elements, while retain the formatting?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, jakarta-mail

I have try to implement the java mail api to read body of the message and store it into text file if it contains contents.

I can able to read the body of the message but it comes with some html elements.

I have added below code in which I have used.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("hostname", "username", "password");
    String result = null;
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    javax.mail.Message messages[]=inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
    for(Message message:messages) {
        System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(message).text());
    }
```

How can I remove those html elements in retrieved message?

Please anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Could you add an example output with HTML elements to your question?

Comment: @Frederic..,If I run above code it will show content of the mail.
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal">Hi<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Data is written in this mail.<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>

but my mail message is"Hi Data is written in this mail." only.I need to retrieve this message only using java

Comment: If you really only want to remove all tags `Jsoup.parse(message.getContent().toString()).text()` should do it. Otherwise you have to be more specific, if all HTML tags are likely and wich elements need to result in line-breaks and so on.

Comment: If i use "jsoup",All are comes in single line only. if I have 100 lines in mail then it will comes all line showed in single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all HTML tags in your mail use the jsoups `text()` method.

**Example Code**

```
String htmlString = "<div class=\"WordSection1\"> <p class=\"MsoNormal\">Hi<br> <br> <br> <br> Data is written in this mail.<br> <br> <br> <br> <o:p></o:p></p> </div>";

System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(htmlString).text());
```

**Output**

```
Hi Data is written in this mail.
```

If specific elements should be result in **line-breaks** similar to the rendered HTML source, you could add line-breaks and then [avoid pretty printing](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint-boolean-) it, when you jsoups' [`clean` method](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist-org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings-).

> **prettyPrint**
>
> If disabled, the HTML output methods will not re-format the output,
>   and the output will generally look like the input.

**Example Code**

```
String htmlString = "<div class=\"WordSection1\"> <p class=\"MsoNormal\">Hi<br> <br> <br> <br> Data is written in this mail.<br> <br> <br> <br> <o:p></o:p></p> </div>";

htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("<br>", System.getProperty("line.separator") + "<br>"); // do replacements for all tags that should result in line-breaks

Document.OutputSettings settings = new OutputSettings();
settings.prettyPrint(false); // to keep line-breaks

String cleanedSource = Jsoup.clean(htmlString, "", Whitelist.none(), settings);

System.out.println(cleanedSource);
```

**Output**

```
 Hi



 Data is written in this mail.
[... four more empty lines]
```

Comment: All data contents which is retrieved from api will be showed in single line only not like mail message structure

Comment: @Mahendran That is the expected output, since you remove the formatting. You should clarify your question: "How can I remove those html elements, while retain the formatting?". Also: which elements style need to be imitated? E.g. what is about tables, etc.?

Comment: I had changed the question. And I need to remove <p> tag ,there is no <tr><tg> tag but table present in the mail content. How can I remove <p>,&nbsp in retained html element.

Comment: It can remove the tags but it shows in single line only not shows like mail

Comment: @Mahendran Have you tried the second solution using `settings.prettyPrint(false)`? As you can see from the pasted output, line-breaks are definitely there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126596/discussion-between-mahen-dran-and-frederic-klein).